# C# EF-relationship 0..1-1 between two entities when the dependent one has only foreign key and no primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-relationship

How to set EF-relationship between two entities where the first(main) entity has a primary key, but the second(dependent) one has no PK, only foreign key - on the first entity.

```
public class Dogovor
{
    public int Key { get;set; }
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public virtual DogovorStatus Status { get; set; }
}

public class DogovorStatus
{
    public int StatusKey { get; set; }

    //public int DogovorKey { get; set; }  // - no need, because this key is pointed in DogovorConfiguration        
}
```

[image: DB tables]

I tried to do like this, but with no success:

```
public class DogovorConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Dogovor>
{
    HasKey(v => v.Key);
    Property(v => v.Key)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)
        .HasColumnName("DG_Key");
    Property(v => v.Name).
        .IsRequired()
        .HasColumnName("DG_Name");

    HasOptional(v => v.Status)
        .WithRequired()
        .Map(v => v.MapKey("ST_DGKey"));
}

public class DogovorStatusConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<DogovorStatus> {

HasKey(v => v.StatusKey);  // not unique - logical error
Property(v => v.StatusKey)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasColumnName("ST_StatusKey");
}
```

I can't add a PK to DogovorStatus. What's the correct way to point such type of EF-relationship?

**EF 6.0**

Answer (score 1):

Add navigation property to DogovorStatus class as well:

```
public class DogovorStatus
{
    public int StatusKey { get; set; }
    public virtual Dogovor Dogovor { get; set; }
}
```

Then adjust the Configurations:

```
public class DogovorStatusConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<DogovorStatus> 
{
    HasKey(v => v.StatusKey);
}

public class DogovorConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Dogovor>
{
    HasKey(v => v.Key);
    Property(v => v.Key)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)
        .HasColumnName("DG_Key");

    Property(v => v.Name)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasColumnName("DG_Name");

    HasOne(v => v.Status)
        .WithOne(s => s.Dogovor)
        .HasForeignKey<DogovorStatus>(s => s.StatusKey);
}
```

Please also see for reference [Configuring One To One Relationships](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-one-relationship-configuration)

Comment: Where do you map to the column:  ST_DGKey?  I can't see it at this example. I'm assuming the database schema itself can not be changed...

Comment: Yes, I can't change the database schema. And I use EF 6.0, not Core

Comment: note that this is a "hack" since the model does not match the schema, which may result in the Initializer being run even if no real model changes occured. This in turn means two things: 1. it could be necessary to use the initialization strategy null in all contexts mapping this type, 2. migrations will have to be done by hand